# A group that is "prime" to an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am having trouble understanding this excerpt from an article ([Characters and Decomposition of a Representation in a Number Field](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X83900306/1-s2.0-0022314X83900306-main.pdf?_tid=4617d632-1c7b-11e7-ac9c-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1491670324_7a6234e197e14f2fa193eaec8e9f4920) by Joseph Lewittes):

> Let $A$ be an ideal of a ring $R$ of algebraic integers in a number field. The group of residue classes $\bmod{A}$ prime to $A$ has a representation $U$ on the space of functions $R\bmod{A}$.

I am relatively new to abstract algebra, and having some trouble understanding how a group can be prime to an ideal? What does this mean, am I just completely misinterpreting this?

Comment: If $S$ is any ring with unity, there is a group $S^\times$ of the invertible elements of $S$.  Here, I assume that the author is referring to $(R/A)^\times$, the residue classes in $R/A$ that have an inverse.  I read the language as "the group of (residue classes prime to $A$)".  In other words, the residue classes, not the group, are prime to $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not saying the group is prime to $A$, it's saying the elements of the group are prime to $A$, in the sense of "relatively prime".  If $R$ is a Dedekind domain and $A,B\in R$ are nonzero ideals, we can say $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime if they have no common prime factors.  For an element $r\in R$, we then say $r$ is relatively prime to an ideal $A$ if the principal ideal $(r)$ is relatively prime to $A$.  Equivalently, the image of $r$ in the quotient ring $R/A$ is a unit.  So the group being referred to here is the group of residues in $R/A$ of elements $r\in R$ relatively prime to $A$, or equivalently just the group of units in the ring $R/A$.